# SQL Server VPN Replication

Tags: replication, vpn, database-replication

I have a requirement to use Sql replication from a sql server 2005 instance to a Sql 2000 instance over a vpn.  The vpn is permanent between the 2 sites and there are only a few tables that need replicated.  Can anyone give me any advantages/disadvantages of replication over vpn or any issues with replication between SQL 2005 and Sql 2000.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I think as long as the amount of data is not that much and speed is not a k.o. criteria,
this will work from the networking point of view. I have several applications communicating
via VPN which basically works smoothly, but of course latency is notably higher compared to
nonVPN communication.

HTH